# Setting Property after Button was clicked correctly for other View

Tags: .net, xaml, data-binding, maui

I have a ContentView in a ContentPage which has some Evaluation Logic with evaluation of the Inputs are valid/invalid. There is a Label which is displayed only in case the Intputs are not valid. There are mandatory and optional Inputs in the ContentView which is determined based on a property.

The ContentPage has a Button which has an RelayCommand-Implementation in the VM of the ContentPage.

So, when I display the ContentView there is no Input yet and therefore all Mandatory fields show Errors. In my opinion it would be better that the Errors are shown only in case the "Save"-Button was clicked. Unfortunately, the Binding of the Button is in a different File - it is in the VM and the evaluation logic for the Labels showing the Error-State are in the Code-Behind of the ContentView.

First of all, I was thinking of Updating a Flag that represents that the "Save"-Button was clicked and then it would be fine to display the Errors in the ContentView.

How can I realize that? The Evaluation should be later and not as the Flags-Options "ValidateOnValueChanged" determines in the XAML

**XAML of the ContentView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Views.MyControlView"
             x:Name="this">

    
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertBoolValueConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>
        
    <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference this}">
        <Grid Margin="20, 0, 20, 0">
            
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="{Binding NameLabelString}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding IsOptionalLabelString}"  FontSize="12" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                <Entry Text="{Binding EntryInput}" Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderString}" Keyboard="{Binding KeyboardSetting}" Margin="5, 0, 5, 15">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>

                        <toolkit:CharactersValidationBehavior IsValid="{Binding InputValid}"
                                                              Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged"                                                              
                                                              CharacterType="Alphanumeric"
                                                              MinimumCharacterTypeCount="1" />
                                                
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </Entry>
                <Label Text="{Binding NameLabelString}" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding InputValid, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolValueConverter}}"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

**Code-Behind of the ContentView:**

```
namespace MyApp.Pages.Views;

public partial class MyControlView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NameLabelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NameLabelString), typeof(string), typeof(MyControlView), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsOptionalProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsOptionalLabelString), typeof(string), typeof(MyControlView), string.Empty);


    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryInputProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryInput), typeof(string), typeof(MyControlView), string.Empty, BindingMode.OneWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty InputValidProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InputValid), typeof(bool), typeof(MyControlView), true);


    public string NameLabelString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(NameLabelProperty); 
        set => SetValue(NameLabelProperty, value);
    }

    public string IsOptionalLabelString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(IsOptionalProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsOptionalProperty, value);
    }


    
    public string EntryInput
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(EntryInputProperty);
        set => SetValue(EntryInputProperty, value);
    } 

    public bool InputValid
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(InputValidProperty);
        set
        {
            // Before everything is initialized TextValidation should be valid
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsOptionalLabelString) || IsOptionalLabelString.StartsWith("Optional"))
            {
                value = true;
            }
            
            SetValue(InputValidProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputValid));
        }
    }


    public MyControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Content-Page (MyPage):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages.Views"
             x:DataType="viewModels:MyPageViewModel"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.MyContentPage"
             Title="...">

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Label 
            Text="Description"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Padding="20" />

        <StackLayout>
            <controls:MyControlView NameLabelString="Name 1:"
                                               IsOptionalLabelString="Mandatory"
                                               PlaceholderString="a placeholder"
                                               EntryInput="{Binding NameOneFromViewString}"
                                               InputValid="{Binding NameOneInputValid, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <controls:MyControlView NameLabelString="Name 2:"
                                               IsOptionalLabelString="Optional"
                                               PlaceholderString="a placeholder" 
                                               EntryInput="{Binding NameTwoFromViewString}" />

            <StackLayout Margin="20, 50, 15, 0">
                <Grid RowSpacing="10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    
                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
                            Text="Save"
                            Command="{Binding SaveItemCommand}" />

                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
                            Text="Cancel"
                            Command="{Binding CancelItemCommand}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel of the ContentPage:**

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MyApp.Pages.Views;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MyPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // Input Values

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string nameOneFromViewString;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string nameTwoFromViewString;


        // Validated Inputs if allowed

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool nameOneFromViewValid;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool nameTwoFromViewValid;


        private bool InputsValid => NameOneFromViewString && NameTwoFromViewString /* && SaveButtonWasClicked */;



        [RelayCommand]
        async Task SaveFoodItem()
        {
            // Could trigger an Update to the ContentView-Codebehind that this Button was clicked
            // so that the InputValid-Property in the ContentView-Codebehind could have a
            // a Flag that this Button was clicked and the ContentView can display Error-Labels
            // ...  <-- don't know how to realize

            try
            {
                if (!InputsValid)
                {
                    // ...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", e.Message, "OK");
            } 
        }  
    }
}
```

I tried to set a boolean value once the Save-Button was clicked so that the InputValid-Property also use this Flag and then evaluate the rest of the Boolean Flags to set the InputValid-State correctly

Comment: Could you please post the full code of `MyPageViewModel ` and current page or share a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT - I changed the code above and also added the ContentPage so that you can test on your side. Basically, as soon as the SaveButton was clicked the user should see if the all Mandatory Field have values. I have also the label with "Red" font that displays the actual Error message. Well, in my opinion, this could also be replaced with an Icon that shows that there are errors and mandatory fields do not have a value.
In the Code-Behind of the ContentView there is the "InputValid" property which is Bound to the View and could also have the "SaveButton-was-clicked" state

Comment: Actually, you can create the `Clicked` method for the button to control the code behind the ContentView.  In the .cs file you can write the code to check if there are some empty input.

Comment: But it is in a different ContenView or to be more precise the Button-Click is handled in the ViewModel of the ContentPage whereas the Entry’s to be evaluated are in a ContentView and therefore different ViewModel/Code-Behind

Comment: I found that the BindableProperty  `NameLabelProperty`  and `IsOptionalProperty ` are not used correctly . The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

Comment: So, I do not fully understand: should I change the naming of the Properties having the getter/setter to NameProperty and remove the suffix „Property“ in the BindableProperty above?

Comment: For more  information, you can check the official document [Xamarin.Forms Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties).

Comment: Although they are in different files. You could pass the value from viewmodel using BindableProperty. Why not add a BindableProperty for costom control which controls the IsVisible property for label.